# No Hits : Not Receving the Traffic data for my website in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Website is not receiving the Traffic data it shows the notifications

NO Hits : Property Answergen is not receiving hits. Either your site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly.

The issue started in July 2015 before that i have been receving the traffic data

The website name is answergen.com

Kindly help me to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: I can see the request to GA going out, so the problem is with your account - you either have used a wrong Account id or, more likely, you have set up a filter that accidentally deletes all data. Look in the admin section into the history widget to see if there were any changes to filters in July 2015. When in doubt set up a new view without filters and look into the realtime reports to see if data comes in.